# Connection refused error while using python-Instagram API

Tags: python-2.7, instagram, httplib, httplib2, instagram-api

I tried to run a simple code to extract data from Instagram using [Python-Instagram](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram) module

The code is

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
api = InstagramAPI(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
```

I am getting a `Connection refused` error at the last lineline. Its because `Python-Instagram` module uses `httplib2` module also. The error looks like this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/httplib2-0.9-py2.7.egg/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1060, in connect
raise socket.error, msg
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

How to resolve this? Do I have to provide any connection specifications for using this module?

Comment: I provided the `client ID` and `client secret` in the arguements

Comment: `api = InstagramAPI(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')` Instagram provides `cient ID` and `client secret` for developers.

Comment: This could mean that your credentials are not correct.